# iOS frame-by-frame animation with Quartz

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, opengl-es, quartz-2d

I'm working on an iPhone game that involves only two dimensional, translation-based animation of just one object. This object is subclassed from UIView and drawn with Quartz-2D. The translation is currently put into effect by an NSTimer that ticks each frame and tells the UIView to change its location.

However, there is some fairly complex math that goes behind determining where the UIView should move during the next frame. Testing the game on the iOS simulator works fine, but when testing on an iPhone it definitely seems to be skipping frames.

My question is this: is my method of translating the view frame by frame simply a bad method? I know OpenGL is more typically used for games, but it seems a shame to set up OpenGL for such a simple animation. Nonetheless, is it worth the hassle?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without knowing what kind of complex math is going on to calculate the translations. Using OpenGL for this only makes sense if the GPU is really the bottleneck. I would suspect that this is not the case, but you have to test which parts are causing the skipped frames.

Generally, `UIView` and `CALayer` are implemented on top of OpenGL, so animating the translation of a `UIView` already makes use of the GPU.

As an aside, using `CADisplayLink` instead of `NSTimer` would probably be better for a game loop.

Comment: CADisplayLink is a good idea, thanks. As for the bottleneck, I somehow neglected to remember that there is in fact another animation which is basically a series of lines that updates every frame. I realize that this, which is currently drawn with Quartz, is probably the bottleneck and should be done in OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the iPhone simulator is it has access to the same resources as your mac. Your macs ram, video card etc. What I would suggest doing is opening instruments.app that comes with the iPhone SDK, and using the CoreAnimation template to have a look at how your resources are being managed. You could also look at allocations to see if its something hogging ram. CPU could also help.

tl;dr iPhone sim uses your macs ram and GFX card. Try looking at the sequence in Instruments to see if theres some lag.